# Cakephp: Email Error SSL

Tags: email, cakephp, ssl

**config->email.php**

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://mail.myserver.co.in:465',
    'username' => 'support@myserver.co.in',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'template' =>false,
    'layout' => false,
);
```

**function to send email**

```
public function sendEmail() {

    $layout = "gmail";
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email -> config('gmail');
    $Email -> from(TEST_FROM);
    $Email ->to(TEST_EMAIL);
    $Email -> subject('Welcome to TaskBucks');
    $Email -> emailFormat('html');
    if ($Email -> send()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

**Error i am facing**

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
ssl://mail.rapidsoft.co.in:465:25 (Unknown error)
```

Comment: Are you sending email from localhost?

Comment: nop i am using my gmail account to send the message but yeah my project is still on my local machine not on any server

Answer (score 0):

Your script is right.

The reason is because you can't send email from your local machine. You need to configure sending email from your local machine then your cakephp sendMail function works.

Here is one of the way you can configure your local machine to send email. If you are using WAMP

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/